# react mutation observer should call one time with updated callback function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dependencies, mutation-observers

I have created custom hook for mutation observer on document as below.

```
const setObserver = useCallback(() => {
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
        viewPinCallback(mutations);
    });
    const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
    observer.observe(document, config);
}, [viewPinCallback]); // need to set blank array []
```

```
const viewPinCallback = useCallback(
    (mutations) => {
        // console.log('viewPins called');
        viewPins.map((pin) => {
            changePinVisibility(pin, mutations);
        });
    },
    [viewPins, changePinVisibility],
);
```

```
const changePinVisibility = useCallback((pin, mutations) => {
    ...
}, []);
```

1. set observer using setObserver (dependencies viewPinCallback)
2. created viewPinCallback as observer callback  viewPinCallback have dependencies of viewPins, changePinVisibility

.

Issue is:
currently setObserver called mutliple times whenever viewPins array changed (which have performance issue currently)
that need to be called only one time with blank dependencies array
by changing to blank dependencies to viewPinCallback not getting called whenever viewpins value changes.

can any help me find out logic that can setobserver to be called only once.